# ckeditor problem on Windows system

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

i'v got a trouble, i want to use Ckeditor with my project, i have Windows with Zend Server installed (apache2, php 5.2, mysql5), encoding is utf-8. When i initialize ckeditor or another elRTE editor i have error: **syntax error
[Break on this error] \n** 
all html is valid, if i delete doctype line, script says that error in another line: **XML cannot be the whole program...**
 jQuery work's fine, i think that problem is in the config of apache or php, can somebody help! Thx a lot!

Comment: Could you add the code where you declare and initialize the editor?

Comment: sure! - http://pastebin.com/Dx1hhYK5 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a problem! i include js lib with short path like - /ck/ckeditor.js , it was the wrong way. When i change it to full path http://site/ck/ckeditor.js, trouble was gone! :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to write the whole path! It's enough to leave the first / out. Means `ck/ckeditor.js` instead of `/ck/ckeditor.js`